# iOS8 can receive push notification but not iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

```
/*--- Setup Push Notification ---*/
    //For iOS 8
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)] && [UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    //For iOS 7 & less
    else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }
```

Hi! I hope someone can help me out there. I have updated my code in order to get push notification for iOS8. Everything works fine on iOS8 device, however it seems the push notification does not work anymore on iOS7 device. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }

        #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif
```

And other push related Methods.. this will work in both ios..

Hope this will help you.